# Android install apk programmatically error - Package Parse error

Tags: android, android-manifest, permission-denied, android-install-apk

I create an Edittext at my page, to allow user to update the apps by downloading the apk and install.  I am using loojp library to handle the Asynctask.

My code at activity:

```
f0textupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            try {
                view.setEnabled(false);
                final ProgressBar f0progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.f0progress);
                f0progress.setProgress(0);
                mHttpClient.get("http://google.com/apps.apk", new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(lastcreated) {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, File file) {
                        //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
                        try {
                            String path = file.getParent()+"/"+ CfgMain.siteid+ ".apk";
                            File dst = new File(path);
                            if (!dst.exists()) {
                                try {
                                    dst.createNewFile();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

                            // Transfer bytes from in to out
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            int len;
                            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                out.write(buf, 0, len);
                            }
                            in.close();
                            out.close();

                            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                            installIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                            installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(dst), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            installIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                            installIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
                            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(installIntent);

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
                        int totProgress = (int) (((float) bytesWritten * 100) / totalSize);
                        if (totProgress > 0) {
                            f0progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            f0progress.setProgress(totProgress);
                        }
                    }

                });
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    });
```

Manifest.xml

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

It prompt an error message "Package parse error".

1) do I need to convert the filename as per the original apk name after download, as the "File file" seem storing as a temporarily name without extension

**Update 1**
Error from logCat:

05-17 11:17:19.142    4562-4562/? W/zipro﹕ Unable to open zip '/data/data/com.M28/cache/77lori.apk': Permission denied

05-17 11:17:19.152    4562-4562/? W/PackageParser﹕ Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/data/com.MMM/cache/MM.apk
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml

**Update 1.1**
- change the Onsuccess()

- add in additional permission at Manifest.xml

Comment: ok, i got this error "Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of... "

Comment: Facing the same problem. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok found a [solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5272/stuck-on-running-downloaded-apk-there-was-a-problem-parsing-the-package) from other forum(xamarin) and solve my problem..
You need to save the APK to a public directory.

For example:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/MM.apk";
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be the issue with min sdk version. if you tried to install on lower sdk then you might  get this type of error